# Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: complete, task_priority, text, user, user_id

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Todo list which has seperate users with their own list.
Initially I had the models.py as:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Todo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='Test User')
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    task_priority = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='high')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

But then when im trying to link single user with its own set of todotask(text field) and its priorites and status.

I added one to one field like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key='user_id') #new
    text = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='Test User')
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    task_priority = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='high')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

It threw an error like this:

> FieldError at /
>   Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: complete, task_priority, text, user, user_id

I didnt completely understand the concept of one to one fields and looking at the tutorials online im confused weather I need to make another table and link it to the Todo table or add another field with some primary key?

Help me understand this concept.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Todo
from .form import TodoForm,ContactForm
import datetime 
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
import json



def index(request):
    todo_list = Todo.objects.order_by('id')
    form = TodoForm()
    mydate = datetime.datetime.now()

    context = {'todo_list': todo_list, 'form': form, 'mydate':mydate}

    return render(request,'todo/index.html',context)

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'todo/login.html')


@require_POST
def addTodo(request):
    form = TodoForm(request.POST)
    text_input = form.get_cleaned_data['text']
    priority_input = form.get_cleaned_data['task_priority']
    if form.is_valid():
        new_todo = Todo(text = text_input, task_priority = priority_input)
        # new_todo = Todo(text = request.POST['text'])
        new_todo.save()
    return redirect('index')

def completeTodo(request, todo_id):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
    todo.complete = True
    todo.save()

    return redirect('index')

def deleteCompleted(request):
    Todo.objects.filter(complete__exact=True).delete()

    return redirect('index')

def deleteAll(request):
    Todo.objects.all().delete()

    return redirect('index')


def emailView(request):

    todo = Todo.objects.all();
    task_list = []
    status_list = []
    for item in todo:
        stritem=str(item)
        task_list.append(stritem)
        if item.complete == True:
            status_list.append('complete')
        else:
            status_list.append('incomplete')


    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            #maillist = Todo.objects.all()
            email_list=dict(zip(task_list,status_list))
            strlist = json.dumps(email_list)
            content = message + strlist
            try:
                send_mail('Todo List', content ,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[from_email])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})

def successView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

**New models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="")
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    task_priority = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='high')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Encountered

> IntegrityError at /add NOT NULL constraint failed: todo_todo.user_id

Comment: can you post your views that direct to '/' as stated in your url and also the template that the view is rendering?

Comment: If you case is single can have more than one todo then use `ForeignKey`  instead of `OneToOneField`. and `primary_key=True`

Comment: The chances of error maybe that you might be using `Todo.objects.get('id')` to fetch the id for the Todo object. So it would be easier if you post your views here.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key='user_id')
```

isn't at all doing what you think it is. `primary_key` expects a boolean, not a field name, and isn't to do with the relationship at all. Because the string `'user_id'` is not empty, this is being interpreted as True, and is equivalent to:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
```

which means that `user` is now the primary key for the Todo model. This is not what you want.

Remove that `primary_key` clause.

Comment: Before using the pk as 'user_id' I did use it as boolean. I gave it another shot and encountered the same error. I have updated the question with the views.py file as well to have a look.

Comment: You need to remove `primary_key` altogether, and migrate. Until you remove it, Todo will not have an `id` field.

Comment: Im sorry this might be a silly question but how do we delete it? Should I drop table and make migrations again?

Comment: Normally making migrations would be enough but since you're effectively adding a primary key it will get complicated. If you don't have any data you care about, it might be better to drop the db and start again.

Comment: I dropped the table and cleaned everything. Made fresh migrations and its still showing the same error. It is even pointing to index.html which didnt happen earlier. I have added an image to the question.

Comment: But did you actually remove `primary_key`  from the definition? Show your updated model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192046/discussion-between-umang-mistry-and-daniel-roseman).